# Sort the results by most views

Tags: laravel

I have results from the "items" table, associated with the "items_views" table, where it records each view.

I would like to sort the results by most views in this code of mine, I know there is something simple but I can't find the right syntax and I couldn't find it in the documentation.

```
$items = Items::whereHas('category', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 1); // only where the category it belongs to is active
})->whereHas('hot', function ($query) { // "hot" is the relationship with the "Items_views" model

    $query->orderBy('item_id_count', 'desc'); <-- EXAMPLE

})->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
    $query->where('access', 1); // only by users with a public profile
})->where('visible', 1)
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->orderByDesc('id')
    ->paginate(25);
```

EDIT:

My database tables:

```
Items: id, user_id ecc
Items_views: id, item_id, user_id ecc
```

My Models:

- Items.php
- ItemsViews.php

This is the relationship inserted inside the "Items.php"

```
public function hot(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ItemsViews::class);
    }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that item views table has multipe rows for an item or there  is single row with count column ?

Comment: The items_views table records multiple rows for the same item (associated with each user).

Comment: I have updated my answer , have a look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a one to many relation between item and item_views table then you need to correct your mapping as

```
public function hot(){
    return $this->hasMany(ItemsViews::class);
}
```

and then you can use `withCount` in your query and order your results with views count like

```
$items = Items::withCount('hot')
    ->whereHas('category', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 1);
    })->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
        $query->where('access', 1);
    })->where('visible', 1)
      ->where('status', 1)
      ->orderByDesc('hot_count')
      ->paginate(25);
```

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items_views.items_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `items`.*, (select count(*) from `items_views` where `items`.`id` = `items_views`.`items_id`) as `hot_count` from `items` where exists (select * from `categories` where `items`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` and `status` = 1) and exists (select * from `users` where `items`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `access` = 1) and `visible` = 1 and `status` = 1 order by `hot_count` desc limit 25 offset 0)

Comment: I added the 'item_id' field in the "hot" report. Solved, thank you very much!